# Jquery ajax response, deep id property disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

This is weird, as I never faced such issue before, below is the situation

Response which I can see in the network . json is quite large, pasting this deep object

```
0   {…}
id  1
packName    "Pack 01"
```

then I have this code

```
$.ajax({
       url : 'https://'+host+'/'+pathV+'/getPlans',
       type : 'GET',
       dataType: "json",
       processData: false,
       contentType: 'application/json'
    }).done(function( resp ) {
        console.log(resp);
    }).fail(function( resp ) {
            console.log( "Data Saved: " + resp.responseText  );
    });
```

What I can see in console is below

```
0: {…}
​​​​
packName: "Pack 01"
​​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​​
length: 1
```

I am wondering where is the "id" field, it just disappears, I am unable to access it via JS also.
Somebody shed some light on this. :)

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle for your problem ? Difficult to debug otherwise.

Comment: is it possible that where you have the data from, `id` was replaced by `length` ?

Comment: Whats in the object?